# gRpc netty creating .dll files windows

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, grpc, netty

In the `temp` folder of tomcat (version 9.0.43) I noticed that there are numerous `.dll` files with this pattern name: `io_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative_windows_x86_***SOME_RANDOM_NUMBER***.dll.

I noticed that a `.dll` file is created at least once when tomcat starts, but I'm not sure if it is being created also at runtime by some operations.

In this java project these are the dependencies that could matter..

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.8.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-vision</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.8.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

In order to not create so many `.dll` files that in the long run can clutter up the system's memory, is there a way to tell the java webapp to use only one `.dll`?

I tried a temporary solution found at this [link](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/21788) but it didn't work out for me.

This one is another [solution](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/10182) I found but I'm using an ApplicationRunner of Spring to run some stuff, I don't know how that one could help..
One way I guess is to run an instruction inside the ApplicationRunner to delete those `.dll` files but I don't really like this idea.

Comment: What problem do you have?

Comment: Updated the question, my bad. The problem is with the number of .dll files that are generated, in the long run they are a lot, so I need a way to clear them or, much better, to tell "somehow" the application to not create as many dll files but use only one, or the minimum needed

Comment: You say "so many .dll files". How many? 10? 100? The files should be deleted when Tomcat shuts down.

Comment: In my case tomcat doesn't go down very often, the number could reach hundreds I'd say, but what's important for me is that at some point the system has no more memory and it crashes, so I need to find a way to delete those .dll files before there is no more memory on the system

Answer (score 0):

The .dlls are not created continually. But they could be created each time you deploy a war. Due to Windows behavior, they can't be safely deleted while the Java process is running.

You can disable netty-tcnative (which may impact performance) by starting tomcat with `-Dio.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.noOpenSsl=true`. The performance difference if using Java 8 can be large. If you use Java 11 or later, the difference is much smaller.

Comment: Tried with that variable but it creates another .ddl file instead with this name "conscrypt_openjdk_jni-windows-x86_6416817510159210000.dll" every time tomcat is started (the last number is changed everytime) so unfortunately it didn't really help..